# How to change User-agent string in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently trying to figure out where and how to change the user-agent string in WooCommerce Webhooks.

The data posts smoothly to requestb.in, but for the service, I'm trying to connect to I need it to be a browser as its always rejected.

```
user-agent: **WooCommerce/2.6.14 Hookshot (WordPress/4.7.3)**
content-type: application/json
x-wc-webhook-source: https://sandbox.testserver.com/
x-wc-webhook-topic: order.created
x-wc-webhook-resource: order
x-wc-webhook-event: created
x-wc-webhook-signature: Xo6ESt2e6CqtAVHzPRBP38OMsPEZrTOLFi12313123Og
x-wc-webhook-id: 574
x-wc-webhook-delivery-id: 9
```

I haven't been able to find a plugin to do it, so I'm trying to track down the location of this string so I can alter it or prepare something to replace it.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Comment: found it in the core files. looks like Ill just mod it there and see what happens